# In how many ways can a pair be distributed over a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose a set $S$ of size $n$.
Let $P$ be all pairs of $S$ such that an element can only be paired with $k$ other elements. Hence, the size of $P$ is $\frac{nk}{2}$.

The question is: how many subsets of $S$, of size $g$, contains at least one element of $P$?

At first I tried
$$ \frac{\frac{nk}{2} \binom{n-2}{g-2}}{\binom{g}{2}} $$

And my reasoning was: I select a pair of $P$ and combine it with all subsets of $S$ of size $g-2$, that does not contains any of the two elements already selected, to create subset of size $g$. Then I divide by $\binom{g}{2}$ because that's the number of permutations of the pair in the created subset.

However I figured out it's wrong because $\binom{g}{2}$ does not represent the correct number of permutations of the pair, and now I don't really know how I should calculate this number.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer the question. For example, suppose that $n=6$, $k=2$, $g=3$. Then:

- One possible choice of $P$ is $\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,5\}, \{4,6\}, \{5,6\}\}$. In this case, out of the $\binom 63 = 20$ subsets $A \subseteq S$ of size $3$, all $20$ must contain an element of $P$: any $A$ contains either at least two of $\{1,2,3\}$ (and contains one of the first three elements of $P$) or at least two of $\{4,5,6\}$ (and contains one of the last three elements of $P$).
- Another possible choice of $P$ is $\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\},\{4,5\}, \{5,6\},\{1,6\}\}$. In this case, out of the $\binom 63 = 20$ subsets $A \subseteq S$ of size $3$, only $18$ contain an element of $P$: the exceptions are $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{2,4,6\}$.

The answer depends on the structure of $P$, not just the size of $P$, or even on how many pairs contain each element.